# how to creat horizontal Page as MySpace.Com?

Tags: php, html, css

How to create a horizontal page like MySpace.Com?

I must set CSS to: `height: window.height()`, `width = total each div in page`, but it is inconvenient if I want to expand more div without relation with width of body

Here is a [sample fiddle](http://jsbin.com/IKACosI/1/edit)

I must set width of body as :

```
body {
       width:4000px;
}
```

and inside div, it must : `float: left`, it will have horizontal layout, if not have width parameter, it also not horizontal

Comment: Can you clarify if you're looking at help at getting your page to scroll horizontally? OR issues with sizing and page layout due to horizontal layout?

Comment: look at this Example: http://jsbin.com/IKACosI/1/edit

i must set width of body: 4000px; it will have horizontal layout, if not have width parameter, it also not horizontal

Answer (score 0):

For Horizontal:

http://jsfiddle.net/YFt3H/4/

use: `overflow-x:scroll;`

Also i have set the parent `div` width manually.If you want dynamic you will have to use JQuery.

Comment: thank but that 's not i want to, look this example, http://jsbin.com/IKACosI/1/edit
i want to Body Horizontal. not div :)

Comment: use overflow for body then

Comment: body{
  height:900px;
  overflow-x:scroll;
 }

ALSO NOT SCROLL,...HMM

Comment: YOU SEE THIS http://cyrilmasson.com/t/personnal-work/
it not use span instead div...
hmm.. i want to all div inside a div horizontal

Comment: can you help me for write a demo website like this?

Comment: i have done this,
<div class="container-outer">
   <div class="container-inner">
      <!-- Your images over here -->
   </div>
</div>
With this stylesheet:

.container-outer { overflow: scroll; width: 500px; height: 210px; }
.container-inner { width: 10000px; }

thank all and happy coding!